# New 20.04 install does not fill the whole monitor

Tags: display, display-resolution, amd-graphics, monitor

Just installed 20.04 on my old desktop and initially the display was about 100 pixels too far left, cutting off the dock. I changed the refresh rate and auto-adjusted the monitor which lines the top left and bottom left, but there's a big gap on the right. I'll include a picture for clarity.

It's a VGA monitor connected with an adapter to the HDMI output of the graphics card, an AMD Radeon RX 480. I understand the problem might well be with the adapter but it works fine with Windows on this machine and monitor.

Thanks in advance for any advice, and see picture below.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/uMurqn4]

Additional info:
DGM L-2266WD monitor - cheap generic Chinese thing with refresh rate 50-60hz

The monitor is 1080x1920 standard widescreen
Ubuntu resolution is set to 1080x1920

I have tried the available framrates: 59.94, 60.00, 60.00 (I have two options for 60 for some reason)

Comment: You have not said what make/model of monitor or what resolution you are running at in Windows and what resolution you are running at in Ubuntu. I would find out the native resolution and refresh rate of the monitor and ensure your Ubuntu display settings are set to output that resolution/rate.

Comment: Sorry if the post was unclear, but it's a DGM monitor you can see in the picture, and it's running at 1920*1080 settings in Ubuntu. It's the same monitor and machine that worked with Windows installed earlier today. The monitor is 50-60hz native and 1080*1920. It's a standard cheapo widescreen desktop monitor, nothing fancy, the only software on it does colour correction, h and v position, phase and clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A silly solution! My monitors autoadjust was rubbish, I loaded a full screen game, hit autoadjust on the monitor again and it filled the screen.